# QDateEdit Select Section Text on Single Click

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qt5.6, qdateedit

I have a `QDateEdit` with current date as default and the date format as "`dd/MM/yyyy`". When I click on the Month then the MM text should be selected. Also, when I click on the date edit the cursor position of the `lineEdit()` returns 0 as the cursor position.

If I click on the Month then the current section returns as Day section (based on date format), since the cursor position is 0. By default the cursor position is 0 So the current Section gives as Day (based on date Format).

By default it happens on the Double Click event. But how can we achieve this on single click?

I have tried using the event filter. But it didn't work.

```
if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
{
        QMouseEvent *mouseevent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
        if(mouseevent != NULL) 
        {
            if(mouseevent->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
            {
                    setSelectedSection(currentSection());
            }
        }
}
```